# Can't use volatile and synchronized in KMP project for iOS source set

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, android-multithreading

I'm trying to develop a KMP library and I'm not able to use @Volatile and synchronized for iOS source set.

For @Volatile, the error is: ***Declaration annotated with '@OptionalExpectation' can only be used in common module sources***

and, for synchronized, the error is: ***Unresolved reference: synchronized***

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: There is no analogue of the @Volatile and `synchronized` in Kotlin Native.

Comment: What could be the alternatives?

Comment: Instead of @Volatile, AtomicReference can be used (or AtomicInt, AtomicLong and AtomicNativePtr for Int, Long and NativePtr). But it's far from being ready to use.

Comment: To anyone looking for an answer to this question, use the concept of freeze in Kotlin/Native. Go through this codelab: https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Kotlin%20Native%20Concurrency/03_Global